# flexbox height based on content in first column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a "panel" which is divided into two equal width columns, the first one contains text and the second one an image. The image is large and should be scaled down to cover the right side. The height of the panel should follow the amount of text in the left side.

[image: This is what it should look like]

This is what it should look like, the image is using `object-fit: cover;` so that it fills its container completely, **but I don't want to have `max-height: 200px;` on .panel**.

Is this possible somehow (preferably without using JavaScript)?

```css
.panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: red;

  /* I want this to be flexible based on text in panelText */
  /*max-height: 200px;*/
  
}
.panel .panelText {
  padding: 1em;
  flex: 1;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.panel .panelImage {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section class="panel">
  <div class="panelText">
    <h3>This is a header</h3>

    <ul>
      <li>One one one</li>
      <li>Two two two</li>
      <li>Three three three</li>
      <li>Four four four</li>
    </ul>

    <p>Now we're at the end</p>
  </div>

  <img class="panelImage" src="https://placebear.com/1000/1000" />

</section>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible, but you shouldn't let image decide about size of its container - make it `position: absolute`. Flex container will always adjust to the biggest element so `object-fit: cover` is pointless here.

Alternatively, and I'd reccomend this, use the image as a background-image for a div (if it's viable on your website setup).

First solution here:

```css
.panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: red;      
}
.panel .panelText {
  padding: 1em;
  flex: 1;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.panel .panelImage {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.panel .image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section class="panel">
  <div class="panelText">
    <h3>This is a header</h3>

    <ul>
      <li>One one one</li>
      <li>Two two two</li>
      <li>Three three three</li>
      <li>Four four four</li>
    </ul>

    <p>Now we're at the end</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img class="panelImage" src="https://placebear.com/1000/1000" />
  </div>
</section>
```

Second solution - background-image:

```css
.panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: red;      
}
.panel .panelText {
  padding: 1em;
  flex: 1;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.panel .image {
  width: 50%;
  background-image: url('https://placebear.com/1000/1000');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<section class="panel">
  <div class="panelText">
    <h3>This is a header</h3>

    <ul>
      <li>One one one</li>
      <li>Two two two</li>
      <li>Three three three</li>
      <li>Four four four</li>
    </ul>

    <p>Now we're at the end</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice solution! But I'm not sure it will hold up when the text grows to something longer than the height of the image when it's 100% wide? That's why I wanted to use `object-fit: cover`, to ensure that it is always covered with the image. Maybe better off using background-image?

Comment: Then your only option is using background-image. `object-fit` won't work in this case and it's not even covered by all browsers properly. http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit
I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Senthe, second solution works great. When collapsing the layout to `flex-direction: column;` (for mobile), I added a `height: 200px;` so that the background image is visible.

Comment: Happy I could help.